# javascript/python time processing fails in chrome

Tags: javascript, python, time

I am writing a timer web app,which records start time and stop time.It uses `javascript,jquery1.4.2` for the front end and `python` for backend code.When a start button is clicked ,start time is saved in a javascript variable.when the button is clicked again, stop time is saved in another variable.These values are passed as hidden parameters to the python code which gets the start,stop values  from  `django`'s `request` parameter.

I expect the start/stop parameters values to be in the following format

```
"07:16:03 PM"
```

so that it can be parsed using `'%I:%M:%S %p'`format string.
I am getting this correctly in `mozilla firefox`.But when I use `chrome`,I only get

```
"19:16:03"
```

This causes value error when I try to parse it with the above format string.

```
import time
...
def process_input(request,...):    
    start_time=request.POST[u'timerstarted']
    ...
    fmtstr='%I:%M:%S %p'
    start_time_list = list(time.strptime(start_time,fmtstr)[3:6])
```

I tried putting `alert('start time set as'+start_time)` in javascript to find what values are set in the page's hiddenfields

With firefox ,I got

```
start time set as08:03:09 PM
stop time set as08:03:43 PM
```

but with chrome

```
start time set as20:04:21
stop time set as20:04:32
```

My knowledge of javascript,jquery is minimal.Why is the script behaving differently in these two browsers? Below is the javascript snippet

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var changeBtnStatus=function(){
    var timebtnvalue=$('#timebtn').attr("value");

    if (timebtnvalue =="start"){
        ...      
        var start_date=new Date();
        var str_time=start_date.toLocaleTimeString();       
        var timerstartedfield =$('#timerstarted');              
        timerstartedfield.attr("value",str_time);        
        alert('start time set as'+str_time);

    }
    else if (timebtnvalue=="stop"){
        ...            
        var stop_date=new Date();
        var stp_time=stop_date.toLocaleTimeString();        
        var timerstoppedfield =$('#timerstopped');
        timerstoppedfield.attr("value",stp_time);             
        alert('stop time set as'+stp_time);       
    }
};
var timerBtnClicked=function(){   
    ...
    changeBtnStatus();
};

$('#timebtn').click(timerBtnClicked);

...
}
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want the string of the time in locale, using the toString method you can provide your own format, or use toUTCString().

toLocaleTimeString is especially meant to display the time as the user is used to, you want it in a set format.

So instead of start_date.toLocaleTimeString(), you want to use start_date.[toUTCString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString)().

Comment: I guess that will give me "Fri, 12 Aug 2011 15:02:45 GMT"..I will have to process it in python then..thanks..will try

Comment: The output will indeed change, but it will be constant over each browser. You could use toString to give it your own format, it will make parsing it easier since you can decide what information is sent.

Answer (score 1):

Why format the time in JavaScript and parse in Python, and even submit yourself to the confusion of different locales?

Try using [Date.getTime](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp) insteam:

```
start_time = (new Date).getTime();
stop_time = (new Date).getTime();
```

This gets you the time in milliseconds since the epoch, which should always be stable.